# LifeCycle of Prepare(forSegue:....)

Tags: ios, swift

Problem that I'm having is to understand what is happening when I invoke `prepare(forSegue:)` method. I get the mechanics of data being pass from `MainVeiwController` to `SecondViewController`. In particular while passing value, I can't initialize @IBOUTLET of `SecondViewController` from `MainViewController` but I can initialize other optional properties like `var name:String?` of `SecondViewController`. Just bit curious about it.

Further elaborating the Question:

> Class for Main View:

```
class MainViewController:UIViewController{
  ..
  ..
  ..
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let yourVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
        // this doesn't throw any error
        yourVC.someData = self.someData

        // this throws an error 
        yourVC.textLabel.text = self.someData

      } 
   }
}
```

> Class for Second View:

```
class SecondViewController:UIViewController{

@IBOULET weak var textLabel:UILabel!
var someData:String?
..
..
..
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question by explaining what happens that you think should not be happening, or what is not working that you think should have worked?

Comment: What value are you trying to assign to the outlet?

Comment: You can't access the IBOutlets because the view isn't loaded yet.  Try calling `loadViewIfNeeded` on the destination view controller in `prepareForSegue` and then access the IBOutlets

Comment: One important thing though, You should not call `prepare(forSegue:)` your self, it's reserved for system, you should call `perform(segue:)` and system will call `prepare(forSegue:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `UIViewController` instance is created, it does not contain any view (unless you've added them in initializer yourself - please don't do this).

when a viewController is about to be presented for the first time, it checks if `view` is `nil` or not, if it is nil, it will load itself from a nib or storyboard and *inject* view to viewController and calls `viewDidLoad(_:)` for you, hence in `prepare(forSegue:)` system only instantiate a viewController for you (based on segue destination type) and you have to configure it's `data`, NOT it's views. If you want to have control over views you can call `loadViewIfNeeded()` which will force the viewController to load it's view (which this is an anti-pattern, use it if it's your only choice).

## Normally this is how it's done:

You define some variables that are settable from outside. ex: `var someString: String!` which tells the compiler to ignore if this value is nil or not (or set some default value if you prefer). And in your `viewDidLoad()` method, assign them to related views that you know.

We know, this kinda breaks `OOD`, but that's the only option you have when you're using storyboards, because system is responsible for instantiating and loading/unloading views/viewControllers. If you want to code cleanly, you can define a viewController and set it's view by `nib`, and handle all these things in initializers. (but be careful, you have to conform to system rules for loading view, unloading view or ..., because these tasks are highly process and memory consuming, so that's why they're defined this way)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: One thing I missed, If you initialize a viewController in code, it _can_ work with storyboards too, i said `nib` in my answer as an example

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` in `SecondViewController` is always called **after** `prepare(forSegue:)` so within `prepare(forSegue:)` all `IBOutlet`s of  `SecondViewController` are not connected yet and could not be accessed.

Comment: So other properties -- `var someData:String?` -- of `SecondViewController` is connected then in `prepare(forSegue: )` ?

Comment: Yes, but properties are never going to be *connected*. The view controller instance with its properties is **initialized** but the associated view is not **loaded** (yet).